# Use RDP port as a proxy for traffic or kubectl commands

Tags: kubernetes, proxy, remote-access, rdp

I'm having an issue with some client access. I have my working machine - Station A - where I have kubectl, helm, terraform, etc.

The client have created VM in their own network for the work. Only these VMs have access to cloud resources as its IP range whitelisted. - This is Station B

All I have is access to Station B through RDP port. And That is it, I don't have permissions to create\start or even see what is allowed in firewall.

Is there a way I can use my RDP port access to Station B to be able to proxy traffic ( or at least `kubectl` commands) From Station A to Station B and then to Cloud?

Installing any software is most likely a no-go. I will have to make requests for the new ports to be opened, which will not happen. The exception could be SSH port, but only slightly better chances.

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge i am 99.9% sure you can not use RDP as you would use ssh to tunnel traffic. Also as you do not have access to the k8s cluster, i think that was intended by the sysadmin, therefore you should contact a sysadmin to provide you access instead.

Comment: On the other hand you could try a portable port forwarding tool like https://www.simpleportforwarding.com/download, but risk to have interference while trying to connect to RDP as there are more then 1 service listening on 3389 that if you even get it to work as it may see the port already being used on the win machine

Comment: I thought about it. Client policy won't allow installation of such application, so no go( But Thanks anyway)